# hibernate - cascading type persist for many to many relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-many, hibernate-cascade

I have two classes Policy and Acl. They have a ManyToMany relationship in them.

// Policy

```
public class PolicyEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "POLICY_ID")
    private int policyId;   
    @Column(name = "POLICY_NAME")
    private String policyName;
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinTable(name = "POLICY_ACL",joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name = "POLICY_ID"),
                                    inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name = "ACL_ID"))
    private List<AclEntity> aclList = new ArrayList<AclEntity>();
}
```

// Acl

```
public class AclEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "ACL_ID")
    private int aclId;  
    @Column(name = "ACL_NAME")
    private String aclName;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "aclList")
    private List<PolicyEntity> policyList = new ArrayList<PolicyEntity>();
}
```

Now when I use Cascade type as persist then I got the following error :

```
Hibernate: insert into POLICY (POLICY_NAME, POLICY_ID) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into POLICY_ACL (POLICY_ID, ACL_ID) values (?, ?)
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: hibernate.AclEntity
```

Whereas when I use cascade type as all then it saves the policy entity and acl entity successfully.I am unable to understand how that is happening.
Note : I am just performing the save operation.

Here is the main code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        PolicyEntity policyEntity = new PolicyEntity();
        AclEntity aclEntity = new AclEntity();

        //policyEntity.setPolicyId(1);
        policyEntity.setPolicyName("Policy 3");
        //aclEntity.setAclId(1);
        aclEntity.setAclName("Acl 3");

        policyEntity.getAclList().add(aclEntity);

        Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().
        applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        session.save(policyEntity);

        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
    }
```

Comment: Show the code that is causing this issue

Comment: Added answer, try it once

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `session.persist()` instead of `session.save()`

Refer to hibernate docs for clear details:

1) [Session.persist():](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#persist%28java.lang.Object%29)

> Make a transient instance persistent. This operation cascades to
>   associated instances if the association is mapped with
>   **cascade="persist"**

2) [Session.save():](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#save%28java.lang.Object%29)

> Persist the given transient instance, first assigning a generated
>   identifier. (Or using the current value of the identifier property if
>   the assigned generator is used.) This operation cascades to associated
>   instances if the association is mapped with **cascade="save-update"**

Comment: I read "CascadeType.PERSIST : means that save() or persist() operations cascade to related entities." on http://howtodoinjava.com/2014/09/25/hibernate-jpa-cascade-types/ , and can you please tell the difference between using persist and save

Comment: @FurquanAhmed, Persist will not return an id where as the save method returns the generated id.

Comment: can you please explain how does that effect cascading ??

Comment: @FurquanAhmed, Given clear information, you can refer the hibernate docs. The link which you are looking at might be giving wrong information.